# Calling method from another class from another file C#

Tags: c#, .net, methods, call

I have declared a namespace in Feed.aspx.cs . This namespace contains a class and this class contains a method:
**Feed.aspx.cs**

```
namespace GetUser
{
public class MyFeedClass
{
   public string getUserID()
   {

       MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
       HttpContext.Current.Session["x"] = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
       string test = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["x"];
       return test;
   }

}
```

}

Now, from **MyPage.aspx.cs**, I'd like to call the getUserID() method. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are using Asp.NET?

You should create a new class inside your add_code folder.
Move that namespace and the class inside the new created class

Then call it from your Feed.aspx.cs:

```
GetUser.MyFeedClass myfeed = new GetUser.MyFeedClass();
string result = myfeed.getUserID();
```

Comment: Yes, and this error pops up: The type or namespace name 'GetUser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do not declare the namespace and the class inside the aspx.cs, create a new class inside the app_code folder

Comment: @TudorGafiuc, In addition, your application will be better structured declaring your classes out for the aspx files.

Comment: Thanks Carlos, I will definetly post more questions in the future, as I'm trying to build a mini social network for my license project. Cheers!

Comment: @TudorGafiuc. Stackoverflow rocks!. See you around ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the namespace in your code-behind:

```
using GetUser;
```

Make the public function a static one in the MyFeedClass:

```
public static string getUserID() {...}
```

Then in your aspx.cs page you can now try to do:

```
string userId = MyFeedClass.getUserID();
```

Comment: I tried with "using GetUser;" and it was showing the same error - "The type or namespace name 'GetUser' could not be found". I worked it out with the above suggestions :) thanks anyway!